# Loading DWF document with 3D annotations in Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are trying to load a local 'DWF' document into the Viewer according to what is explained here: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/dwf-and-pdf-support-forge-viewer

The DWF file is created from an Inventor Part and contains 3D annotations. The Viewer inside Autodesk Vault client is nicely showing the annotations, but when we load the same DWF file into the Viewer in our own web application the 3D annotations are not shown. See images below. Is there an extension which we should load\enable?

The last image below is showing the annotated 3D model on viewer.autodesk.com. The 3D annotations are not shown there either. I've used the same DWF file as Vault is using to display on the View tab.

Regards,
Pim Saarloos

[image: DWF loaded in Viewer in Autodesk Vault client]

[image: DWF (the same) loaded in de Viewer in our own web application]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The DWF Extension is an older tool and is not being updated. The best approach is to use the Model Derivative API where DWF is fully supported.

You should create a simple Viewer APS application that will enable you to upload and view your models on the Viewer. You will thus be able to leverage the Model Derivative API.

You can get started by creating a simple Viewer application by following the main APS tutorials: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your feedback. If I use the same DWF file of the annotated 3D model and upload this to viewer.autodesk.com the annotations are NOT shown either. After uploading the DWF file goes through the Model Derivative service if I am correct. The question remains; which extension is used by Autodesk Vault to show the 3D annotations correctly?